# CodeMirror and variable height for title with markdown

Tags: javascript, codemirror

Codemirror allows us to use variable height ([see this demo with some markdown](http://codemirror.net/demo/variableheight.html)) and with the markdown syntax you can write a title with `#` or underline it with `=` or `-`.

Unfortunately variable height only works if tags and title are on the same line, if we use `=` the title is not bigger:

[image]

I have try to code something ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BafS/PMJ8f/)) but it is hacky not very clean and don't work in all situations.

Someone has an idea? Is there a clean solution? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [issue](https://github.com/marijnh/CodeMirror/issues/839) was finally closed the 22 Jun 2017. The lookahead was implemented in CodeMirror 5.27.0.

The function [`lookAhead`](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#modeapi) is able to handle the n-th line and thus is it possible to implement what I needed with a clean solution.

The [variable height example](http://codemirror.net/demo/variableheight.html) was updated and the bug is not present anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible, as CodeMirror doesn't support lookahead - the mode must decide how to style the `header` line before it gets to see the `======` line.

There is [an open issue](https://github.com/marijnh/CodeMirror/issues/839) to add 
lookahead ability.